# Excel macro to reference cell text

Tags: excel, vba

I am putting together  a basic macro to format a column to include reference letters. For example, one column has `1,2,3` and there is a cell where the user can input some letters and click a button. `ABC` for example. This when working shall format `1,2,3` to now be `ABC1`, `ABC2`, `ABC3` etc.

I have achieved this somewhat but it only works for the letter A. See below:

```
Sub Macro4()

    Range("A3:A60").Select

    Selection.NumberFormat = Range("k11").Text & "0" & "0" & "0"

End Sub
```

Comment: The cell contains `1, 2, 3` or each row has a different number?

Comment: If the answer to @tjb1's question is each row has a different number then just use a formula like `=$K$11&A3`. Otherwise, use VBA.

Comment: Yes sorry so each cell in the column would be an incremental number 1, 2 , 3 , 4 ,5 etc. By clicking the button it will add the reference to the front.

Comment: @85l00k85 A macro would do that, but do you want the ability to change the reference? Say, from `ABC` to `DEF`?

Comment: Thanks for responses. Yes, with the code above I have got it to work. However it will only work with the letter A or combinations of multiple A, A, AA etc. So the idea is that whatever reference the user inserts into the chosen cell K11 this will be placed in front of the column numbering system which is more than likely going to remain 1,2,3,4,5,6,7...etc.

Comment: @85l00k85 I just wanted to know if it needs to be changed after running. Because once it runs there is no back button. Therefore, it will need to remove the attached reference from the numbers to add the new reference if it is run a second time. Make sense?

Comment: Thanks Brian. Yes that makes sense but it is not vital. It would be interesting to see it that way also.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt. I'm quite certain there is a better way:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMacro()

Dim MyRange As Range
Dim MyReference As Range
Dim MyArray() As Variant
Dim Counter As Long
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Dim Cell As Range
Dim val As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
Set MyRange = Range("A3:A60")
For Each Cell In MyRange
    val = Application.Evaluate("=MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}," & Cell.Address & "&" & """0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9""" & "))")
    Cell = CInt(Mid(Cell, val, Len(Cell) - val + 1))
Next Cell

Set MyReference = Range("B3")
MyArray = Application.Transpose(MyRange)
For Counter = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
    MyArray(Counter) = MyReference & CStr(MyArray(Counter))
Next Counter

MyRange = Application.Transpose(MyArray)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Barrie ill try it!